# Resolve duplicate routes based on middleware group

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

In `web.php` I have two middleware groups for two user roles - `admins` and `non_admins`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    // if user is logged in AND has a role of admin...
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\IndexController@index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'non_admin']], function () {
    // if user is logged in AND has a role of non_admin
    Route::get('/', 'NonAdmin\IndexController@index');
});
```

Both `admin` and `non_admin` middleware check that the role of `Auth::user()` is `admin` or `non_admin` respectively; if it's not, the middleware fails with `abort(403)`. *Why do I not have a single middleware?* The point of this to separate the two roles, so that **each has its own independent controller logic and its own views**.

### Problem

If I log in as an `admin` I get 403, if I log in as a `non_admin`, it works as expected. My guess: Laravel sees the two duplicate routes, and only resolves the one that is defined last (which happens to be in `['middleware' => ['auth', 'non_admin']]`).

### Question

How do I resolve duplicate routes but separate controller and presentation logic? Again, `admin` and `non_admin` users will visit the **same** route ('/') but see two **different** views. *I also want to implement this in two different controllers.*

Comment: Can you post the Middleware classes? Probably the AdminMiddleware is not working as expected.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Notflip Apparently you can't have duplicate routes in Laravel, since they point to the same URL. You could use [Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer) to manage roles.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....

I would personally keep everything encapsulated under a common controller, and perform the necessary checks and modifications using a service class.

But if you *really* want to keep everything separated under two different controllers based on your roles, you could do it this way. This assumes that you're using [Laravel's built-in Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies):

***routes***

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function(){
        $isAdmin = Auth::user()->can('do-arbitrary-admin-task');
        $ns = $isAdmin ? 'Admin' : 'NonAdmin';
        $controller = app()->make("{$ns}\\IndexController");
        return $controller->callAction('index', $parameters = []);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and by service class you mean a middleware?

Comment: No, I mean a Service Class: A class that abstracts away business logic from the Controller.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a class? I have the same issue, thank you!

Comment: [Here's an example using Lumen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375135/lumen-shared-controller/38388074#38388074). Basically, you can use a Service Provider to tell Laravel's IoC container how to handle the dependency injection. Laravel and Lumen's registration of Service Providers are a little different from each other, but not by much. With Laravel, you register each Service Provider in your *config/app.php* file, while with Lumen, you register them in the *bootstrap/app.php* file.